# What happens if state is updated multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run the code below, I expected the counter to be set to zero and start again like `1..2..3` and so on.

But when I click reset (on 5) it goes like `0..6..1..7..2..` and so on.

Why does this happen? What am I missing here? Thanks.

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  setTimeout(
    () => setCounter(counter + 1),
    1000  
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>setCounter(0)}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to run this kind of effect in a `useEffect` hook. That way, you can run the effect whenever `counter` is updated and provide a mechanism to cancel an existing timeout.

When the `timeout` hits 1 second, the `counter` stateful variable will be incremented. Since `counter` is specified in the `useEffect` dependency array, the effect will run again, queuing up another timeout.

We return a *cleanup* function from our `userEffect` hook. This is important because, if our `counter` is changed by some other mechanism (e.g., the `Reset` button), we'll want to cancel the in-progress timeout to start over!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = (props) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(
      () => setCounter(counter + 1),
      1000  
    )
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [counter])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>setCounter(0)}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why my code behaves the way it does. Can you please elaborate on that? Why does it go 0..5..1..6..2 instead of 0..1..2..3..? like two separate threads?

Comment: I added some detail to my answer about how the effect works, but essentially what you were experience was happening because the `setTimeout` had closure around the previous `counter` value, which was `5`. When that timeout resolved, even if you clicked reset before it resolved, it would still increment based on the variable at the time it was queued up.